# Inno Setup shortcuts for folder are not opening in Windows 10

Tags: windows, inno-setup, shortcut

A setup installer created in Inno is not opening folder shortcuts correctly in Windows 10.

The folder location is in the source programs Program Files location: 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM"
This is an older XP win32 application, if that info helps.

What I want is to create these folder shortcuts located in the Start Menu and the Desktop of the user so they can access the source.

The Inno code: (notice the first and fourth commands, both include the Flags for folder shortcut.

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userprograms}\ABC Company\Ported Program for Windows 10"; Filename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM"; Comment: "Ported Program (comment)"; IconFilename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM\PPicon.ico"; Flags: foldershortcut
Name: "{userprograms}\ABC Company\CT"; Filename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM\CT.exe"; Comment: "CT Prog"
Name: "{userprograms}\ABC Company\Uninstall Ported Program for Win10"; Filename: "C:\Windows\unins000.exe"; Comment: "Uninstall Ported Program"
Name: "{userdesktop}\Ported Program for Windows 10"; Filename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM"; Comment: "Ported Program (comment)"; IconFilename: "C:\Program Files (x86)\ABCCOMPANY\PORTEDPROGRAM\PPicon.ico"; Flags: foldershortcut
```

The program is installed by the user, which is why I tried {user...}. An earlier attempt used {common...} which did not resolve. I haven't tried {group...} because I'm not sure what that does.

When attempting to open these files, I get this dialog box.
[image: Attempting to open Inno created icons/shortcut]

It seems like a normal shortcut...
[image: Ported Program folder shortcut]

Any ideas why the shortcut doesn't open correctly?

Comment: It is really annoying when you censor the path when your whole issue is path related. Is "PORTEDPROGRAM" just "something" or "something.exe"?

Comment: Sorry, but wanted to keep the program information confidential... PortedProgram is the directory name and not an EXE. The shortcut is not based on an application, but to open the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `PORTEDPROGRAM` is a directory and you wish to create a shortcut to the directory then the **target directory must exist** before the shortcut is created. (Should not be a issue because `[Dirs]` and `[Files]` are [executed before](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_installorder.htm) `[Icons]`)

You should also remove the `foldershortcut` flag because it creates a special folder shortcut that is not supported on Windows 7 and higher. You can create a shortcut to a folder without this flag.

Comment: Ah I see. So another tidbit of information, now that I realize its relevant... [Files] is copying a series of installers, and [Run] executes the batch file that installs in sequence. So it must be creating the shortcuts prior to the completed installation of those installers, and its directory! That makes sense based on the installation order. Thank you.

Comment: would it make more sense to create the shortcut (*.lnk) files and expect that Inno copies the shortcut files (via [Files]) to the aforementioned location? Or is it better practice to use the batch file that is under the [Run] command to copy the *.lnk files? I'm trying to write/test both but if they both options work, which is best practice?.

Comment: Inno doesn't copy .LNK shortcut files in the [Icons] section, they are created on the fly with the IShellLink COM interface on the target system.

Comment: Definitely using the batch to copy shortcuts to %userprofile%... I did so because the batch runs the series of installers first and if I used inno it would be as Anders mentioned above, a shortcut would be created in [icons] before the installer is able begin [run]